# Giving collaborators permission to run meteor deploy

Tags: meteor, deployment

I would like to know how to give other people permission to run `meteor deploy [siteUrl]` to deploy the app to `[siteUrl]`.

Right now I can run it fine by myself. But my teammates also need to deploy and I don't know how to give them access. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [meteor authorized](http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-developer-accounts) command for this.

From the documentation:

Run

```
$ meteor authorized <app name>
```

to see the list of users who are authorized to access your app.

You can add other users with

```
$ meteor authorized <app name> --add <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

Addig to MasterAM's answer:

[Un]fortunately, you can only get the authorized info for your own apps. Here is a transcript of my asking for that info for my own app (platypus) and for another app which I tried to deploy to (not knowing the name was already taken), which resulted in my being prompted for username and password (meatier):

```
C:\Meteor\platypus>meteor authorized platypus
clayshannon

C:\Meteor\platypus>meteor authorized meatier
Couldn't get authorized users list: You are not authorized
```